# How can I remove some unwanted urls from sitemap.xml

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are using java dxa 2.0 and default `navigationcontroller.class` for generating `sitemap.xml`.

Now how can I remove some unwanted URLs (ie. some AJAX calls, email template pages and others)?

Is it possible to generate 1 consolidated `sitemap.xml` in root publication for 2 different child publications (English and Arabic)?

Answer (score 1):

DXA offers 2 OOTB ways of generating the sitemap, static and dynamic. You can read more [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v11&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-4A757BE5-AED2-4AEE-B9A0-E2A1BEE30C49&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-1223D30F-00CF-45EB-85B9-8E42802AD0FC.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4A757BE5-AED2-4AEE-B9A0-E2A1BEE30C49&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20DXA-v11%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dnavigation&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1566818732191&currentQuery=navigation&currentScope=).

Now depending on which type you use, the default one is static, you will have to do different actions. Either adjust the numeric prefixes or adjust the taxonomy and keywords used by pages.

Yes, but you will have to custom code this yourself and since you want this in the root, that implies that the parent publication is also published.